# Pass a string as standard input to an executable

Tags: c, exec, stdin, pipe

I have `count = read(pipe, buffer, buffsize);` and am trying to run what is received (buffer) through another executable to have a differing process done on it.

`printf("%s", buffer);` prints it out correctly, but running it through `execl("/path", "/path", buffer, NULL);` or a number of other ways I've tried doesn't seem to run the executable. `path` is a compiled executable.

The executable *does* run properly if I use `execv("./path", STDIN_FILENO);`, but that isn't being taken from the pipe. `path` is expecting a the string as standard input.

The situation of the program is that I'm typing in input on one program using a while loop and `read()`, using a pipe to send that text to the program that is running `execl` (nothing else needs to be done in this program), that is then trying to call the executable with the string as an `stdin`. Only the intended input is coming in through the pipe, in chunks when the user presses enter.

An example of a string coming through the pipe is `this is an example`. The executable needs to have this inputted as standard input.

How can I get the string to be used as standard input for `/path` executable correctly?

Comment: There are several different problems tangled up in here; we need more information.  Does the second executable expect its input on its stdin, or as a command line argument?  Does it *not run at all*, or does it just not process the input as expected?  Are you doing `execl` in a child process or the original process?  Is there anything else coming in on that pipe, or is it entirely the intended input for the second executable?  Does the program that's doing all this have other stuff that it needs to do?

Comment: @Zack Thanks, I wasn't sure what all I needed to include. I added some more information

Comment: When the string coming through the pipe is "this is an example", what is the value of `count`?

Comment: @chux The value is `1`

Comment: run the two programs like this: pgm1 | pgm2   Then have pgm1 read from stdin and output to stdout.  Have pgm2 read from stdin and output to stdout.  Then the connection is automatic and all you have to do is type the input, after having started the two programs with the command line, as indicated above.

Comment: @user3629249 Thanks for your input but that's not at all what I'm trying to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like `popen()` is what you're looking for, to open a pipe to your desired executable so you can either pass stuff to its standard input, or read stuff from its standard output.

For instance:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE * p = popen("/bin/cat", "w");
    if ( !p ) {
        perror("error opening pipe");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    fputs("Echo me via /bin/cat\n", p);

    if ( pclose(p) == -1 ) {
        perror("error closing pipe");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox$ ./testpopen
Echo me via /bin/cat
paul@thoth:~/src/sandbox$
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I  didn't make the problem clear or if I'm misunderstanding your answer. The issue is not with transferring text from the input program to the second program via a pipe, it's with transferring the text from the second program to the executable

Comment: @ZachSaucier: And you can use `popen()` in the second program to run the executable and pass the text to its standard input.

Comment: I see. Wouldn't the executable have to be running then? Also I'd prefer not to have to change the executable's code as it was given to us (school project)

Comment: @ZachSaucier: No, it wouldn't have to be running, `popen()` would execute it. `popen()` essentially opens up a shell, runs your executable, and then passes everything you write to the file pointer it returns to that executable's standard input (or reads from its standard output, if you call it with a `"r"` mode). When you call `pclose()`, it'll wait for your executable to terminate, and then return. There's no need to change any code in the executable, as far as it will know it's just getting reading from its standard input as it always would.

Comment: One more clarification (hopefully), sorry for my lack of knowledge. Does it require a `fgetc` in the executable? The examples I'm seeing use it and when I try it without a `fgetc` it seems to not be running just as was the case with `execl`

Comment: It doesn't require an `fgetc()`, but obviously it has to read from its standard input in some way, otherwise passing text to its standard input would be pointless. If it's not making sense to you, posting a minimal compilable piece of code illustrating exactly what you're trying to do would be helpful, along with sample input and output. Passing `STDIN_FILENO` to `execv()` is highly incorrect, by the way.

Comment: Awesome, not sure what was going wrong the first time but after recompiling all the files it works great! Thanks for the help. What's so wrong about passing `STDIN_FILENO` to `execv()`?

Comment: `execv()` expects an array of strings representing command line arguments as its second argument, passing it a small integer instead would be a catastrophic error if it tried to read from that array, and it certainly wouldn't cause anything to happen with its standard input.